# list directories (and subdirectories) of a svn remore repo

Tags: list, svn

I need to list all directories and subdirectories recursively of a remote svn repo,
I tried to use

```
svn list http://....myrepository -R --depth=infinity
```

but I get also the files.

Is there a vay to instruct "svn list" in order to list only the folders without using any post processing as grep...?

Answer (score 0):

No i am pretty sure it is not possible as of release 1.14.

What `svn ls` outputs is path and an option whether the path is a DIR or a FILE(you can check it out by exporting the ls in xml format).
There is a `search` option in svn ls that allows you to search "glob syntax" terms on path. There is no way to pass a glob argument to `search` that will only filter out the directories. You will have to use a post processing like grep or use an output xml file.

Additional example information,
if output from the

`svn list http://....myrepository -R --depth=infinity`

is

```
branch/folder1/
branch/folder1/file.file
```

And you try to search something as

`svn list http://....myrepository -R --depth=infinity --search r"*/"`

You will not get output of only `folder1` as the `/` is added after the list has been outputed to the terminal.

It would be interesting to know the use case though, where this would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately your suggestion does not work with the svn version I have

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.9.12 

.....
svn list http://...myRepo -R --depth=infinity --search r"*/"
Subcommand 'list' doesn't accept option '--search ARG'
```